Jfrog Artifactory Installation Not Working
Getting the service as active & running but UI is not working at http://<my-ip-address>:8082/ui.
Checked the logs of the artifactory service at /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/log/console.log getting below error.
[security_keys.go:172 ] [main] - Master key is missing. Pending for 55 seconds with 2m0s timeout [startup]
[jfcon] [INFO ] [security_keys.go:172] [main] - Master key is missing. Pending for 55 seconds with 2m0s timeout [startup]
[jfevt] [INFO ] [security_keys.go:172] [main] - Master key is missing. Pending for 55 seconds with 2m0s timeout \[startup\]
[jffe ] [INFO ] [] [frontend-service.log] [main] - pinging artifactory, attempt number 60
[jffe ] [INFO ] [] [frontend-service.log] [main] - pinging artifactory attempt number 60 failed with code : ECONNREFUSED

Even after creating a master key manually, I am getting
Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error: Error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping': Get "http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8046: connect: connection refused [startup]

For the above issues followed these documentation resolution but it did not helped
https://jfrog.com/help/r/what-are-the-artifactory-key-master-key-and-what-are-they-used-for/the-artifactory.key
https://jfrog.com/help/r/how-to-resolve-a-service-registry-ping-failed-error-after-an-artifactory-upgrade/how-to-resolve-a-service-registry-ping-failed-error-after-an-artifactory-upgrade
Hi am trying to install the jfrog artifactory pro version 7.84.14. But i am getting the above error. I have used below steps for the installation.

Server --> Amazon Linux 2023 (c7i.xlarge)
The instance security group is all allowed for inbound & outbound
Using openjdk version "17.0.11"
wget https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/artifactory-pro/org/artifactory/pro/jfrog-artifactory-    pro/7.84.14/jfrog-artifactory-pro-7.84.14-linux.tar.gz
mkdir /opt/jfrog/
tar -xvf jfrog-artifactory-pro-7.84.14-linux.tar.gz -C /opt/jfrog/
sudo mv /opt/jfrog/artifactory-pro-\* /opt/jfrog/artifactory
useradd -r -s /bin/false artifactory
chown -R artifactory: /opt/jfrog/artifactory
useradd -r -s /bin/bash artifactory
chown -R artifactory: /opt/jfrog/artifactory
systemctl start artifactory.service
/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/bin/installService.sh artifactory artifactory

I have also tried with the default installation commands for Artifactory 7.84.14

wget https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/artifactory-pro-rpms/artifactory-pro-rpms.repo -O jfrog-artifactory-pro-rpms.repo;
sudo mv jfrog-artifactory-pro-rpms.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/;
sudo yum update && sudo yum install jfrog-artifactory-pro-7.84.14

But i am getting the same error. I am using AWS EBS volume for storage & do not want to use Postgress or other database.
I have tried with different jfrog artifactory versions but getting the same issue.

I had these errors with a fresh installation of version 7.71.23. The problem was a typo in the database URL in system.yaml.

Starting with the Artifactory 7.84 release, when installing a new Artifactory instance with any database other than PostgreSQL, before running Artifactory, you are required to add the following configuration settings to the file $JFrog_HOME/var/etc/system.yaml:
shared:
  database:
    allowNonPostgresql: true

See here:
https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/choose-the-right-database
This was added as part of the push to have Postgres as the preferred default database for all JFrog products.
Please be very careful to indent this correctly as yaml files are whitespace dependent.
You should see the error stating this in the artifactory-service.log:
Caused by: org.jfrog.storage.dbtype.DbTypeNotAllowedException: DB Type derby is not allowed: Cannot start the application with a database other than PostgreSQL. For more information, see JFrog documentation.


I think it's a timeout problem or disk performance problem where DB initialization cannot complete.
I had the same problem, try this:
stop artifactory service, connect to database and drop it , recreate it and add privileges.
Then extend timeout and apply this parameter in systemd file and yaml file:
https://jfrog.com/help/r/artifactory-how-to-resolve-artifactory-timeouts/timeouts-in-jfrog-artifactory-server
Then start artifactory service

For me it got resolved by disabling the IPV6 in the configuration.
